# Running a program with Shell - Compile Error: Object required

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to grab selected Outlook mails, save them to the disk as html and run another application.

While emails get saved I am struggling with running the other application. There is a "Compile error: Object required".

```
Public Sub maile()
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName As String
    Dim enviro As String
    Dim objShell As String

    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
            Set oMail = objItem

            sName = oMail.Subject
            ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"

            dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
            sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
              vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
              vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".html"

            sPath = "c:\maile\"
            Debug.Print sPath & sName
            oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olHTML

        End If

        strProgramPath = "C:\Pedro\dist\Pedro\Pedro.exe"
        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run strProgramPath

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, sChr As String)
    sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know which line of code generates the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of introduction to coding if you're new to this. Type Theory (make sure to learn more about it any other day, it's a beautiful topic!): your *things* in your code have a *type* that describes them. Like, what kind of things they can do and what kind of data they can hold. Types are often divided between *Value Types* and *Reference Types*. Values are native simple things like numbers or strings, they are safe and easy, efficient and nice. References are quite more complex and you can screw them, but they are so powerful and flexible you'll basically love them, like those famous *Objects* in general.

Why is this important in your code? You are basically treating a *ValueType* like a *ReferenceType*. VBA demands from you that assignments to a *ReferenceType* are done via

`Set ReferenceType = value`.

I mean, you are forced spell out a `Set` assignment. And likewise, *ValueTypes* cannot be assigned with a `Set`.

Where did it happen to you? At the beginning, you say

```
Dim objShell As String
```

which means that you're telling VBA that `objShell` is a `String`, that is, a *ValueType*. But later you wrote

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

and after a `Set`, VBA is expecting a *ReferenceType*. That's why it complains with a *Object required* Compile error :)

So, just say at the beginning instead

```
Dim objShell as Object
```

which is by the way what a `CreateObject()` function gives you, Objects :)

PD: off-topic: you should try to improve indention, it makes everything more pleasant to read and it's a universal mantra in programming. But that's a different topic :)

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I have changed string to object and the error message is no longer popping up. Yay ! Unfortunately another problem surfraces. The mails get saved, but when the program that's being launched by the script starts I only get the black window (looks like cmd window) which dissapears immediately, so I am unable to read it. My hypothesis is that the program starts before the mails are saved, so it can't find them and closes. Still, can't tell for sure with the window closing before I am able to read it. Any way around that ?

Comment: Yes, I was able to verify that my program actually starts but is immediately after finished by the script. Tried to make it wait for a given period of time but that's not practical in the situation. Looks like I need to ask new question.

Comment: I'd need more info for this, I don't know Outlook libraries by heart... Have you tried debugging? The F5 and F8 buttons, they do magic. Here a quick googling on the topic, maybe it helps: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html That way you can spot problematic instructions, that's essential to spot problems and possible solutions.